# Связка полей в базе данных

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть 2 таблицы в phpmyadmin. Первая таблица "Дисциплина" - Поля: Код дисциплины и имя дисциплины. Вторая таблица Успеваемость - поля: id и предмет, в предмет вводится код дисциплины. Ниже прилагаю изображение таблиц.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно выводит информацию из таблицы "успеваемость" . Вывожу поле "предмет", там хранятся коды дисциплин. Как мне на выводе получать сразу имя дисциплины?

Comment: Это самая базовая вещь - оператор `select`. И поиском можно найти. И в описание метки есть ссылки на учебники.

Comment: @AlexR. приведите пример, к чему такой комментарий ? Мне нужно из кодов дисциплин в одной таблице, получить имена дисциплин из другой таблицы

Comment: Базовые знания лучше получать из учебников, а не в режиме вопрос/ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
  "Успеваемость"."ID",
  "Успеваемость"."Предмет",
  "Дисциплина"."Наименование"
from "Дисциплина",
     "Успеваемость"
where "Дисциплина"."Код" = "Успеваемость"."Предмет"
```

Comment: Спасибо. Не мог сообразить такую конструкцию)